# О словосочетании "хотя бы"

Tags: части-речи

Является ли словосочетание "хотя бы" какой-нибудь частью речи в предложениях:

- "Возьми хотя бы трёхкопеечную монету." (на столе перед ребёнком лежат одно-, двух- и трёхкопеечная монета),
- "Дай мне хотя бы ложку." (на столе перед ребёнком лежат ложка, вилка и ножик),
- "Принеси мне хотя бы кольцо." (на столе перед ребёнком находятся шарик, кубик и кольцо)?

Если словосочетание "хотя бы" является какой-нибудь частью речи в упомянутых предложениях, то какой именно частью речи является указанное словосочетание?

Answer (score 2):

Это слитное сочетание двух частиц - фразеологизм.

Хотя бы - сочетание употребляется как усилительно-выделительная частица в значении "по крайней мере".

http://elhow.ru/ucheba/russkij-jazyk/orfografija/kak-pishetsja-hotja-by

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Дорогой друх, не привязывайте так сильно математический язык к естественному. У них ну совсем ничего общего.

Comment: Дорогой.

Пожалуйста, не надоедайте.

Answer (score 1):

Хотя бы - это частица (служебная часть речи), составной структуры, с модальным оценочным значением "по крайней мере, как минимум".

Что касается Ваших предложений, то они коммуникативно неверны. Вы предлагаете фразы, которые описывают только часть ситуации, поэтому надо восстановить отсутствующий фрагмент, например так:

Если вся мелочь тебе нужна, возьми хотя бы трёхкопеечную монету.

Дай мне хотя бы ложку, если мама  не разрешает тебе брать вилку и ножик.

Если ты не можешь принести всё сразу, принеси мне хотя бы кольцо.

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь ими распорядиться?

Comment: Я планирую использовать Ваши сведения для обучения С. комбинаторике и играм в карты.